# How do I re-initiate AutoComplete on a WinForm Text Box, after a successful initial AutoComplete?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I have a control, which has an autocomplete textbox. When I enter text into the textbox, I can successfully display the autocomplete dropdown, and auto-fill possible text. When I find the item I want, I select it, call my database and get the object, finally reloading the controls blank fields with the correct data.

The autocomplete textbox is also loaded with the data pulled from the last autocomplete call.

When I delete or try to type in the autocomplete box, it doesn't display any of the autocomplete dropdowns or auto-fill text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the properties you have set to make the textbox autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Auto complete mode to suggest append so that it will suggest one or more suggested completion strings it has.

```
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
```

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer, as it did help address a similar issue! I also wasn't paying enough attention to my method calls, and found that it broke/didn't call the load method once it was re-loaded (due to overloaded constructor.)